How to provide Parameters to controller via $stateprovider.controllerProvider?
I have a custom router where I provide a specific templateUrl and controller via templateProvider and controllerProvider.
$stateProvider
.state('viewProduct', {
    url: '/product/id',
    templateProvider:[....],
    controllerProvider:[
    'input1',input2','input3',
    function(input1,input2,input3) {
     var controllerName = input2[input1];
      return controllerName; //this can be controller1/controller2/controller3 etc.
});

The thing is I want to have each controller handle 2 situations via a flag or just a variable like "full view/partial view/guest" etc.. How do I pass in a variable to the controller here?
